# No Data Found Error in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to insert a data into oracle database(version 11g xe).But when i'm trying to execute the procedure using toad i'm getting the error as 'ORA-01403: no data found'.
Here's my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ACTSINFO.sp_Insert_WorkDetails 
(p_workname IN varchar ,
p_workaddress IN varchar)
IS
BEGIN   
   insert into workdetails (workname,workaddress) values (p_workname,p_workaddress);
END sp_Insert_WorkDetails;
```

I tried to execute the procedure using the below statememt

```
EXEC sp_Insert_WorkDetails('test','test');
```

Also i've defined a trigger and sequence for the autoincrement of workdetailsid in table workdetails

Sequence is as follows

```
 ALTER SEQUENCE ACTSINFO.WORKDETAILS_WORKID_SEQ
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE 0
 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE
 NOORDER
```

Trigger is as follows

```
DROP TRIGGER ACTSINFO.WORKDETAILS_INSERT;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ACTSINFO.WORKDETAILS_INSERT
BEFORE INSERT
ON ACTSINFO.WORKDETAILS
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT WORKDETAILS_WORKID_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.WORKID FROM WORKDETAILS;
END;
```

I'm new to oracle.Pls help me...

Comment: Unless there is a `TRIGGER` defined on that table, I don't see how this exception could be thrown. Can you check that? Do you get the stacktrace for your exception?

Comment: yes,i've defined a trigger for autoincrement of the workdetailsid in workdetails

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your trigger is the problem:

```
SELECT WORKDETAILS_WORKID_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.WORKID FROM WORKDETAILS;
```

If there are no rows in workdetails the select will return nothing. Even worse, if your workdetails table has more than one row this will also fail miserably.

You really want the following:

```
SELECT WORKDETAILS_WORKID_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.WORKID FROM dual;
```

or - if you are on 11g - then you can use:

```
:NEW.WORKID := WORKDETAILS_WORKID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
```

Comment: @RobvanWijk: thanks. I new it was working in my current version, but I didn't know when this was added.

Comment: can u pls explain what do you mean by dual in trigger.Is it any kind of keyword.Sorry for the late response...

Comment: @ksg: what does "u pls" mean? For the dual table, please see the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/datadict.htm#CNCPT1219